# PyCharm get rid of doctest background color

Tags: python, pycharm, doctest

Is there a way to remove the green highlighting in the doctest in PyCharm?

[image]

Or am I doing something wrong in the first place? And that is the reason why the code is highlighted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> am I doing something wrong and that is the reason why the code is highlighted?

The green background is the default syntax highlight PyCharm uses for doctests. So no, there's nothing wrong its purpose is to help differentiate from the surrounding code.

> Is there a way to remove the green highlighting in the doctest in PyCharm?

Yes. You can remove the background color by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Color Scheme` `>` `General` `>` `Code` `>` `Injected language fragment` and changing the `Background` value as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer! I would not mind the highlighting if it did not highlight the whole line. I guess there is no way to stop the highlighting after the last part of code?

Comment: exactly, the ragged edges drive me crazy.  :-)